# Facebook Open Graph in development environments

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

We're developing a web application using Facebook Graph API. Naturally, we have a Facebook application, which I'll call "MyApp" for the sake of this question.

In order that our developers will be able to run and debug the server locally, we have a always-sandboxed Facebook application, which I'll call "MyAppDev". The domain for this application is localhost:8080. This makes it possible to do Facebook authentication on the development machines. This way, we have a different set of auth tokens for development and production, we have short dev cycles, and everyone's happy.

But when it comes to Open Graph, things get a bit tricker. That's because Open Graph objects must be backed by real URLs that are to be accessed by Facebook. Therefore, we can't really define objects and actions on MyAppDev (if we use production URLs in MyAppDev it will be inconsistent with the databases in the developers machines). So it seems that the only option is for developers to collectively use a test server for development, with a third app, lets call it MyAppTest. But this has a few downsides:

1. This breaks the model of developers being able to run things from their own environment. I suspect it will cause slower development cycles.
2. There's no automatic way to synchronize Open Graph configurations (at least not that I've aware of) so we'll need to manually copy the configuration (e.g., actions/objects) from MyAppTest to MyApp. This is quite error prone.

So my question is, what is the common practice for development and testing of open graph applications? Is it anything like I described? Is there a better way?

Thanks in advance,
Yaniv

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> There's no automatic way to synchronize Open Graph configurations (at least not that I've aware of) so we'll need to manually copy the configuration (e.g., actions/objects) from MyAppTest to MyApp. This is quite error prone.

Yeah, this really is a p.i.t.a. – I wish Facebook came up with a better way of doing this; at least a “synchronize” feature would be nice.

As for testing OG objects – only possible solution for testing that from a developer’s own machine that I can see, is to make that machine reachable from the internet; using a DynDNS service of some sort or something similar.

Comment: So I gather you have a separate app for development/testing with a duplicate set of actions and objects as in prod, and you make sure they are synchronized? Then each developer has their machines accessible from the internet? Is this really a common practice?

Comment: At least for us we don’t see any way around having separate development/production apps, and updating OG settings manually – like I said, a PITA, but screwing with the production app while testing new stuff is of course out of the question …

Answer (score 0):

We are having the same issue in our colaborative development environment. At least we can authenticate to facebook from our local copies, but we can't get successful responses from FB.api() when publishing stories.

This is the specific error:

[image]

Let me quote part of the solution proposed from Raj Rathore. We haven't tested yet this solution, but we'll sure do.

> The solution to this problem is either deploy your app online or allow
>   localhost tunneling so that facebook can access it. I prefer localhost
>   tunneling when working in my development environment.

For more details on this, visit to Raj's [website](http://www.rajrathore.com/localhost-tunneling-working-with-facebook-open-graph/)